# VS Code debugger unable to load numpy (32bit) with Python 3.8 (32bit) on Windows (64bit)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda

Currently, I am working on a project in VS Code (64 bit) on windows (64 bit) where I have to use python 3.8 (32 bit). To do so, I am creating an environment in the cmd terminal with

```
conda create -n new_env
```

and then I am setting the condapath to 32 bit via

```
conda config --env --set subdir win-32
```

and install python en numpy via

```
conda install python=3.8
conda install numpy
```

when I then write an empty py file, e.g.:

```
import numpy
a=numpy.zeros(50)
```

and run the code with the debugger I am getting an error when loading numpy:

```
Exception has occurred: ImportError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: _run_module_as_main)


IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.8 from "C:\Users\jenny.kupzig\miniconda3\envs\nasim_py38_32\python.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.21.5"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: %1 ist keine zulässige Win32-Anwendung.
  File "C:\Users\jenny.kupzig\miniconda3\envs\nasim_py38_32\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "C:\Users\jenny.kupzig\miniconda3\envs\nasim_py38_32\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "C:\Users\jenny.kupzig\miniconda3\envs\nasim_py38_32\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "C:\Users\jenny.kupzig\miniconda3\envs\nasim_py38_32\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
  File "C:\Users\jenny.kupzig\miniconda3\envs\nasim_py38_32\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 150, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Users\jenny.kupzig\Documents\NASIM53\nasim-parameternachfuehrung\probe.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\jenny.kupzig\miniconda3\envs\nasim_py38_32\Lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\jenny.kupzig\miniconda3\envs\nasim_py38_32\Lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main (Current frame)
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
```

I've verified already via the debugger that numpy, as well as python version, are 32bit. When I run the debugger via the remote connection on my Mac the debugger does not complain at all. It seems to be a windows issue.

Does anybody has an idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Is the [link](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html) provided in the error content valid?

Comment: The path: `C:\Users\jenny.kupzig\miniconda3\envs\nasim_py38_32...` is the correct one pointing to my environment. Also, the numpy version is the one I've installed.